# highstock chart when move navigate bar under the main chart, the selection disappeared

Tags: highcharts

Once I have made a selection, the columns of selected will turn gray,but when I 
1. make the navigate bar to move onto smaller set
2. the screen size is small.

My selection is gone. 
Anyone knows what's going on? Is this a known issue for highstock?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ma50685a/4/ My code is here

Comment: This is caused by `dataGrouping`. You select some of the grouped-points, but when you change extremes (or resize browser), another level of dataGrouping may kick in, removing old points and creating new ones. `selected` property is not passed on between levels (for example day -> week etc.). You can disable `dataGrouping`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/ma50685a/14/ - but if you have a lot of the points, you may loose some of the performance.

Comment: omg, thank you so much for your help!!!